# Como retirar valor null de um foreach ou array

Tags: php, array, foreach

estou fazendo uma consulta em uma tabela que tem um valor em branco(aluno:nota). Em uma pagina eu faço a função com select e jogo o array em um return para chamar em outra pagina, mas eu não consigo eliminar o valor em branco para imprimir apenas os que possuem dados.

```
$valor = dados_aluno($mysqli);

foreach($valor as $resultado) {

$nome_aluno        = $resultado[1];
$nota              = $resultado[2];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se usares o [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) depois de verificar que a `$resultado[2]` é nulo ele vai passar para o próximo elemento sem executar o código que está depois.

```
foreach($valor as $resultado) {
    $nome_aluno = $resultado[1];
    $nota       = $resultado[2];

    if (empty($nota)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Alterei o `is_null` para ser `empty`, visto que a `$nota` é branco e nao nulo.

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou aqui, não imprimiu nada, nem os positivos estão imprimindo.

Comment: `$nota` é sempre nulo, ou antes mostrava algo? Deu algum erro ou a página está a funcionar normalmente, mas deixou apenas de mostrar os resultados?

Comment: tirei as chaves e funcionou. muito obrigado pela colaboração

Comment: utilize empty!!!

Comment: Devia estar a alterar quando escreveste o comentário :)

Answer (score 0):

Na minha aplicação o exemplo do amigo funcionou sem as chaves. Alterei o if também.

```
$valor = dados_aluno($mysqli);

foreach($valor as $resultado) {
$nome_aluno = $resultado[1];
$nota       = $resultado[2];

if ($nota == "") 
    continue;

}
```